# Pull out minus sign to get a unified list?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given the following list:

```
{a + b, c + d + e, - a + b, a - b, - c - d - e}
```

I would like to get as a result:

```
{a + b, a - b, c + d + e}
```

To clarify: I'd like to transform the first list in such a way that the first term in each element is normalized to a plus sign and throw away any elements that can be obtained from the final result by multiplying with `-1`.

I have tried `Collect[]` and `FactorTerms[]` and some other functions that look remotely like they would be able to do what I need, but they never touch minus signs ....

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Could you add some more examples or a better explanation?

Comment: @Seth: please let me know what additional information you'd need, I mainly like to have a `Union[]` function that normalizes beforehand the first term in each element to have a `+` sign,

Comment: your clarification did the trick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `FactoredTermsList`:

```
In[5]:= FactorTermsList /@ {a + b, c + d + e, -a + b, 
  a - b, -c - d - e}

Out[5]= {{1, a + b}, {1, c + d + e}, {-1, a - b}, {1, a - b}, {-1, 
  c + d + e}}

In[6]:= DeleteDuplicates[%[[All, 2]]]

Out[6]= {a + b, c + d + e, a - b}
```

Comment: built-in to mma, like everything else! I had no idea (as usual), +1

Comment: @Sasha Is this a side effect? I don't find in documentation anything about how the factor extraction should work. Moreover, applying it to `(-a+b)` extracts a -1, but with (-a+1) extracts a 1.

Comment: @belisarius I think the problem here is, partly, what "first" means (in the question). It's not trivial to control the order in which mma arranges terms, so one will eventually be reduced to structural pattern matching or something like that (like in my answer).

Comment: @acl I thought the same until I saw this answer. There should be some logic behind the correct factor extraction, but I don't get it

Comment: @belisarius I guess I should have added "in order to control what "first" means" (although my answer doesn't do that). In any case it would be interesting to find out more about this FactorTermsList, although I am guessing it'll be over my head.

Comment: @belisarius: Fortunately I don't care about the order and just want to get rid of these duplicates, so the internal mma ordering is fine. When you need a specific order, one could wrap numbers in functions `(-a + z[1])` and then mma uses lexicographical ordering (I think)

Answer (score 4):

Replace each by its negative if the syntactic sign of the first element is negative. Then take the union. Example:

```
ll = {a + b, c + d + e, -a + b, a - b, -c - d - e}

Out[444]= {a + b, c + d + e, -a + b, a - b, -c - d - e}

Union[Map[
  If[Head[#] === Plus && Head[#[[1]]] === Times && 
     NumberQ[#[[1, 1]]] && #[[1, 1]] < 0, Expand[-#], #] &, ll]]

{a - b, a + b, c + d + e}
```

Daniel Lichtblau

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to eliminate the elements that are duplicate modulo an overall sign. At least in this particular case, the following will work:

```
In[13]:= Union[FullSimplify@Abs[{a + b, c + d + e, -a + b, a - b, -c - d - e}]] /. 
          Abs[x_] :> x

Out[13]= {a - b, a + b, c + d + e}
```

If the order of elements in the list matters, you can use `DeleteDuplicates` in place of `Union`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt.

```
ClearAll[nTerm];
nTerm[t_] := If[MatchQ[t[[1]], Times[-1, _]], -t, t]
```

is intended to be mapped over a list; takes a single item (of the list) as input, replaces it by its negative if the first element has a negative sign. So `nTerm[-a + b + c]` gives `a - b - c`, which is left invariant by `nTerm`: `nTerm[a - b - c]` gives back its argument.

Next,

```
ClearAll[removeElements];
removeElements[lst_] := 
DeleteDuplicates[lst, (#1 \[Equal] #2) || (#1 \[Equal] -#2) &]
```

takes a list as argument, removes those list elements that might be obtained from another list element by negation: `removeElements[{1, 2, 3, -2, a, -a, "GWB", -"GWB"}]` gives `{1, 2, 3, a, "GWB"}` (!). Finally,

```
ClearAll[processList];
processList[lst_] := removeElements[nTerm /@ lst]
```

applies the whole lot to an input list; thus, `li = {a + b, c + d + e, -a + b, a - b, -c - d - e}; processList[li]` gives `{a + b, c + d + e, a - b}`